# Excel - match wildcard cell value from one table to other

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables...

Table 1:

```
Name
Test Ltd
Test Inc.
Child company ltd
Parent Ltd
Child inc.
Parent company
```

Table 2:

```
Name
Test
Child
```

Result should be:

```
Name               Result
Test Ltd           Match
Test Inc.          Match
Child company ltd  Match
Parent Ltd         No Match
Child inc.         Match
Parent company     No Match
```

What is the best way to do wildcard lookup / match to get above result?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Input the following formula as an array formula in `Table1` `B2` and fill down.

```
{=SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH("*"&Table2!$A$2:$A$3&"*",$A2),0))}
```

Maybe you must change Table2 within the formula to your name of `Table2`.

An array formula is entered in the cell without the curly brackets and then finalized with [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter].

Results >0 are marking matches and results of 0 are marking no matches.

Edit:

```
{=SUM(COUNTIF($A2,"*"&Table2!$A$2:$A$3&"*"))}
```

This array formula is also possible. Please check which of the formulas will have better performance with your data amount.